# pubsub error while deploying the component in lightning web component

Tags: lightning-web-components, pubsublwc

I  have created a pubsub component and i am  trying to  deploye  the subscribe component A and  B and facing the below error

No MODULE named markup://C:pubsub found : [markup://c:pubsubComponentA]

Do we need to use any name space  i have deployed the pubsub to org

ComponentA HTML file :

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Pub sub demo component A">
        <div class="slds-var-m-around_medium">
            <lightning-input type="text" onkeyup={inputHandler} class="slds-m-bottom_medium"></lightning-input>
            <lightning-button variant="brand" onclick={publishHandler} label="publish"></lightning-button>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
    
</template>
```

Js file :

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import pubsub from 'C/pubsub'
export default class PubsubComponentA extends LightningElement {

    message 

    inputHandler(event){
        this.message=event.target.value
    }
    publishhandler(){
        Pubsub.publish('componentA',this.message)

    }
}
```

Comment: Two questions: why a capital "C" instead of lowercase and why use a custom pub/sub instead of using the [Lightning Message Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-message-service/documentation)?

Comment: Yes we can use Lightning message service  yah i got the issue the captial C was the issue i changed it and i am able to deploy the component

Comment: If this is your code, I recommend you ensure you add all the missing ";" characters to avoid any ambiguity. While JavaScript deals with missing ";" in many cases, it may misinterpret what you're doing without them.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the use of a capital "C" for the namespace, instead of lowercase "c".

Change the import from:

```
import pubsub from 'C/pubsub';
```

to:

```
import pubsub from 'c/pubsub';
```